# iOS:saving string data in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

i am developing  contact list app so that i need to bring the contact data and stored in the tableview i did as below

```
     - (void)listPeopleInAddressBook:(ABAddressBookRef)addressBook
   {
     NSInteger numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
    contactList= CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook));

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++)
{
    ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)contactList[i];

   firstName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
 lastName  = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
    NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);

    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    CFIndex numberOfPhoneNumbers = ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < numberOfPhoneNumbers; i++)
    {
        NSString *phoneNumber = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i));
        NSLog(@"  phone is:%@", phoneNumber);
    }
         CFRelease(phoneNumbers);

           }


        }
```

aim getting the data in the strings format that is first name and the last name .my problem is i need to save the data that is present in first name and  last name to array But that array is present out side of the for loop . so that i will pass the array data to the table view .

Answer (score 0):

1.option 1 : Just do one thing create NSMutableDictionary inside for loop. Store all ( firstname,lastname etc) in it.  at last of for loop add it in array. 
2.option 2: create contact as object with required attributes.  See example here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552545/how-to-get-phonebook-contacts-from-ios-device

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)listPeopleInAddressBook:(ABAddressBookRef)addressBook
{

    NSInteger numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
    NSMutableArray * contactList= CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook));

    NSMutableArray *tableviewArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // ADD This Line

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)contactList[i];

        NSString *  firstName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        NSString *  lastName  = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
        NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);




        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        CFIndex numberOfPhoneNumbers = ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers);
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < numberOfPhoneNumbers; i++)
        {
            NSString *phoneNumber = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i));
            NSLog(@"  phone is:%@", phoneNumber);
        }

        [tableviewArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:firstName , @"first_name" , lastName , @"last_name" , nil]]; // ADD This Line

        CFRelease(phoneNumbers);

    }


}
```

Comment: AS u have given tableview array is only for that loop if array comes out of that loop it returns null value  i need to keep data same when ever it has been kept in different methods and what about phone numbers  thanks in advance please help.

Comment: Create a global array

Comment: kk i got but aim getting phone no for last index names only it means its showing phone number for las name only not for all please let me know

Comment: NSString *phoneNumber = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, numberOfPhoneNumbers - 1));

        [tableviewArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:firstName , @"first_name" , lastName , @"last_name" , phoneNumber , @"phone_no", nil]]; // ADD This Line

Comment: kk thank u it got worked and can we able to filter  the name &no by using the search bar can u give me any examples i have tried a lot but i can't able to find id

Comment: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-seachbar-to-tableview-ios7  See if this helps